# Can I make my for-loop in R iterate SLOWER than it is supposed to?

Tags: r, json

I know the question is a little confusing, however, I need to circumvent a 1011 CloudFlare error I keep running into when trying to use a for-loop in some of my data-scraping code (i.e. when using the fromJSON() function to pull data via an API). Essentially, I noticed that I get denied access for every 7th iteration, and was hence wondering if I can make my for-loop iteration slower by 7x in order to scrape all of the data I need.

I hope my question makes sense, if not I will do my best to clarify. Thanks

Comment: You could add a `Sys.sleep(n)`, to stop for `n` seconds.

Comment: Will give it a go, thanks a lot for the suggestion Martin

Comment: Another thought: assuming you're using `httr::GET` or similar, check its return value for the return code. If it is this cloudflare error (indicating you are being throttled), only then do you `Sys.sleep(n)`. That way, you'll get speed until you get the error, then sleep a bit. While sleeping on every call is certainly being polite to smaller API endpoints (for performance), for cloudflare I suspect it's more of a policy thing. (Make sure you're adhering to whatever end-user-contraints they may place on the API.)